# Want to modify drupal default pager functionality

Tags: views, 7, paging

I am creating a page with teaser of articles using views... In the Full pager, the default functionality is....

**1** 2 3 4 ... next >

when i click next now the next number gets highlightd like...

< prev ... 1 **2** 3 4 ... next >

and now when i again click next...

< prev ... 2 **3** 4 5  ... next >

the number set gets altered...

But what i actually need is...

**1** 2 3 4 next >

< prev  1 **2** 3 4  next >

< prev  1 2 **3** 4  next >

< prev  1 2 3 **4**  next >

and now when i click next...

< prev **5** 6 7 8 next >

There are some modules like [PAGERER](https://www.drupal.org/project/pagerer) to change the appearance of the core pager... But is there any to make this functionality or should I do some custom work...

Comment: Personally I think what you want is bad, from the [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) point of view. 
And it is not any of the common pager types. So you probably will need to do your custom work. But for the sake of your users, I hope you will not.

Comment: I do know it... but actually this is what they need me to do... Is there any way to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by implementing `function [THEMENAME]_pager($variables)` inside your theme. Default implementation is shown and described in [`function theme_pager()` documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7).

Comment: Fine it worked... I did some math and made it done... now I am gonna proudly ask them  "do you really need this??"... :)

Answer (score 2):

I worked on it and found a result... actually Drupal core pager is user friendly enough but in case you need to alter it's functionality you need to edit variables in [`theme_pager()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) in your theme's template file.

To obtain the above functionality I altered some variables which are as follows...

```
$pager_first = (floor($pager_current / $quantity) * $quantity) + 1;

$pager_last = $pager_first + $quantity - 1;


if( $pager_current % $quantity == 0){
  $pager_first = $pager_current - $quantity +1;
  $pager_last = $pager_first + $quantity - 1;
}
```

I neglected `$page_middle` variable since I did not needed it...

Warning: Do this when its absolutely necessary...